# How to run Protractor e2e tests with different environment variables (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, protractor, angular6, e2e-testing

In e2e test I want to have environment variable similar to the one as in Angular app. Looks like e2e test project builder `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor"` does **not** support file replacements (unlike builder for web app):

```
"fileReplacements": [{
  "replace": "apps/web/src/environments/environment.ts",
  "with": "apps/web/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
}]
```

So using Angular CLI `ng e2e` command I can switch configurations (or projects in angular.json) and in project configuration I can specify different Protractor configuration files `protractor.conf.js`. My question is: how can I get in e2e test any variable which will be different in configuration files or any other file, similar to the `environment.ts` file(s) in the app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I ended up by using `protractor.conf.js` for environment variables. Main advantage - no need to use any third party lib.
1. Create a Protractor config file for each environment. In `params` specify your variables:

```
'protractor.conf.js'
...
  params: {
    postDeploy: false,
    credentials: {
      username: 'Test',
      password: 'Password'
    },
...
```

Second Protractor config file can use the first one as default and contain only overrides (to avoid duplicates in configs):

```
'protractor-dev.conf.js'

const defaultConfig = require('./protractor.conf');
let devConfig = {
  params: {
    postDeploy: true,
    credentials: {
      username: 'DevTest',
      password: 'DevPassword'
    }
  }
};
exports.config = Object.assign(defaultConfig.config, devConfig);
```

2. Use `configurations` in `angular.json` for e2e project:

```
...
    "myproject-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "apps/myproject-e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "myproject:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "protractorConfig": "apps/myproject-e2e/protractor-dev.conf.js",
              "devServerTarget": "",
              "baseUrl": "https://mywebsite.com"
            },
```

3. Switch configurations in command line using `-c` or `--configuration` parameter

```
ng e2e myproject-e2e -c dev
```

You can also overwrite some parameters in the command line:

```
ng e2e myproject-e2e -c dev --baseUrl=https://mywebsite1.com
```

4. And finally in e2e tests itself, you can use any parameter from config:

```
browser.params.postDeploy
browser.params.credentials.username
```

Comment: using --baseUrl=... on command line of ng is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

There are several parts to my answer so I'll try to keep them short as I can.

For environment variables I use a package called `node-env-run`. You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-env-run). It is really easy to setup and allows you to change environment variables on the fly for local dev. You just setup an `.env` file in the directory you are running the commands from with a list of key/value pairs. Then you run your script like this:

```
nodenv --exec "ng e2e"
```

`Nodenv` will pickup the variables in that file and create the environment variables for the current test run. They are all discarded at the end of the session. It works great for local dev. From there I just setup environment variables in my build tool using the same env variable names as my .env file. Then I reference them in my `params` object in the protractor config. A good example would be for something like database credentials that may be different based on the environment you are running tests against.

```
params: {
    sql: {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        dbname: process.env.DB_NAME,
        user: process.env.SQL_SERVER_USER,
        password: process.env.SQL_SERVER_PASSWORD
    }
}
```

For the second part of your question, how to implement different config files, I just use `Object.assign(defaultConf, environmentConf)` to accomplish this. The properties in the `environmentConf` will overwrite the same properties in the `defaultConf`.

I usually setup a default config that contains all the properties that are going to be common among all the configs. In the environment configs I only put properties that are unique to each environment. An example would be `baseUrl`. Here is an example of what I mean.

**Default Config**

```
module.exports = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000, // Timeout of each script
    specs: [
      '../specs/**/*.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      acceptInsecureCerts : true,
      chromeOptions: {
        args: [
          '--start-maximized'
        ],
        prefs: {
          download: {
            prompt_for_download: false,
            default_directory: path.resolve(__dirname, '../downloads/')
          }
        }
      }
    },
    framework: 'jasmine', 
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true,
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
      print: function() {}
    },
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    onPrepare: function() {
        // ...
    },
    params: { // params object... },
    suites: { // suites listed here... }
}
```

**Local Dev Config**

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8082',
    directConnect: true
}
```

**QA Environment Config**

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: 'https://my-app:7443',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://hub:4444/wd/hub',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
        print: function() {}
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using directConnect for local dev but a selenium hub once the app has been deployed to a given environment. The way I handle this with protractor is I pass in a command line flag `--params.env=localhost`. Then in the protractor config I get the value of this argument and choose what the config looks like based on that. Given the examples above it would look something like this.

From the command line I would run something similar to this `nodenv --exec "ng e2e -- --params.env=localhost"` or `nodenv --exec "protractor conf.js --params.env=release"`. And here is what the conf.js would look like:

```
const env = process.argv.filter(arg => {
  return arg.includes('--params.env');
})[0];

let isLocal = false;
let isRelease = false;

if (env) {
  isLocal = env.includes('localhost');  
  isRelease = env.includes('release');
}

const defaultConf = require('./default.conf');
const localConf = require('./local.conf');
const qaEnvConf = require('./qa.conf');
const releaseConf = require('./release.conf');

let protractorConf = {};

// run tests against localhost
if (isLocal) {
  protractorConf = Object.assign(defaultConf, localConf);
}

if (isRelease) {
  protractorConf = Object.assign(defaultConf, releaseConf);
}

if(!isLocal && !isRelease) {
    protractorConf = Object.assign(defaultConf, qaEnvConf);
}

exports.config = protractorConf;
```

I'm sure there may be better ways to accomplish this but doing it this way allows me to use different configs without having to install another 3rd party dependency. Also, if you want to use the release configuration but run the tests against a staging or prod environment it's simple. Just pass in the `baseUrl` from the command line and it will overwrite anything that is in the config. `nodenv --exec "ng e2e -- --baseUrl=https://my-url/ --params.env=release"`

Comment: First of all `node-env-run` is 3rd party library (I'm trying to avoid as much as I can to use 3rd party libs) and as I understand it requires to be installed globally (which I can't and don't want to do on my build server).  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You don't/won't need it for your build server. You only need it for your local dev environment. On your build server you just setup environment variables and reference them in your build. That's why I mentioned the part about the `params` object. You can reference env variables using `process.env` so as long as your build server creates the env variables in some way you will be fine.